# Render mermaid from markdown

Tags: node.js, reactjs, markdown, swagger-ui, mermaid

I have Swagger UI Node module which should render any code start with ```` ``` ```` to a code block.

What I would do is a small enhancement which made the generated as shown below:

````
```mermaid
your code goes here...
```
````

Into:

```html
<pre><code class="mermaid">
your code goes here...
</code></pre>
```

Note that Swagger UI already generates (without the language specified):

```html
<pre><code>
your code goes here
</code></pre>
```

All needed details can be found in the following URL:

> https://swagger.io/blog/api-documentation/building-documentation-portal-swagger-tutorial/

Comment: I formatted your post the best I could.